# Attempting to ignore unrecognized field in MappingJakcson2HttpMessageConverter

Tags: java, spring

I have an existing Spring-based REST Client that I did not write, but am attempting to fix. One of our remote REST services added a field on us and the JSON parsing broke; I am attempting to set the converter so that unknown fields are ignored in general. I have the following code executing during setup:

```
public void setRestTemplate(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());

    // configure the JSON converter to ignore unknown properties
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = jsonConverter.getObjectMapper(); // new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(jsonConverter);

    this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
}
```

We're using `com.fasterxml.jackson.core`, jackson-core, jackson-databind, and jackson-annotations, from version 2.1.0.

With the above code in place, the REST call still fails with InvocationTargetException, "Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field". If I put the field it mentions into the object getting unmarshalled, the error disappears.

I adapted the above code from other code that used MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter instead of MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter; is that a problem? With this in place, the field is still not ignored, though if I use the annotation to ignore unknown properties, the field is ignored. I'd rather put this at the mapper level, however, so that it applies to all objects with a single configuration.

Does anyone see what I did wrong with the above configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You are adding new `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` instance to the `MessageConverters` list of `RestTemplate` so there will be two `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` instances. You can verify this by putting the debugger on restTemplate. It might be the case that existing instance of `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` is getting picked up instead of customized one. To fix this you can remove the exiting instance and add new one like below.

```
public void setRestTemplate(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    //Remove existing MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter from restTemplate
    final Iterator<HttpMessageConverter<?>> iterator = restTemplate.getMessageConverters().iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            final HttpMessageConverter<?> converter = iterator.next();
            if(converter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter){
                iterator.remove();
                break;
            }
        }

    //Add new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = jsonConverter.getObjectMapper(); 
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(jsonConverter);
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
}
```